# shortcut for edit selected field in Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

What is shortcut for edit selected field in Workbench?

(windows)

in docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html#workbench-keys-menu-edit

They say: Modifier+E

but it's not work, assuming Modifier key is Shift or Alt or Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of lacking info about the context of your question I assume you mean the resultset grid in the SQL IDE, which you get after running a select query. You can edit individual cells either by double clicking the field or by a hotkey. On Mac this is the return key, on Windows F2.

Clarifying the term `modifier`: this is either the Control key (on Win + Linux) or the Command key (on Mac). Shift + Alt are also modifier keys, but they have the same meaning on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

This shortcut work only in Model, EER Diagram context. Try other combination (Modifier+X) and detect Modifier-key.

Use Tab key.